# execution problem in read/write from file exercise (newbie)

Tags: c

i wrote a programe to read integers from a .txt file and put them in an array, it compiles just fine ,but would ask for the number of integers then stops

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void genererN ( int n){
    int i=0;
    FILE* fichier = NULL;
    fichier=fopen("valeurs.txt","w");
    while (i<n){
        fprintf(fichier,"\n%d\n",rand());
        i++;
    }
}

void replirtab (int **t,int n){
    int i=0;int m;
    FILE* fichier = NULL;
    fichier=fopen("valeurs.txt","r");
    char stre[999999] = "";
    while(i<n){
        fgets(stre, 999999, fichier);
        m = atoi(stre);
        *t[i]=m;
        i++;
    }
}

void affichertab (int *t,int n){
    int i=0;
    while(i<n){
        printf("%d\n",t[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

and this is my main function where i ask for the number of randomly generated integers and use my functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "source1.h"
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("donner le nombre de valeurs ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int T[n];

    genererN(n);
    replirtab(T,n);
    affichertab(T,n);
    return 0;
}
```

and the header

```
#ifndef SOURCE1_H_INCLUDED
#define SOURCE1_H_INCLUDED

void genererN ( int n);
void replirtab (int *t,int n);
void affichertab (int *t,int n);

#endif // SOURCE1_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: There is no main() function at all.

Comment: You're not even opening a file.

Comment: Your code have no entry point, as @VillageTech said you should add a main function.

Comment: the main function is in another file and thers nothing in it except the functions you see here

Comment: @KhaledZeffouni could you show us your main function then ?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "source1.h"
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("donner le nombre de valeurs ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int T[n];

    genererN(n);
    replirtab(T,n);
    affichertab(T,n);
    return 0;
}

Comment: `fgets(stre, 999999, fichier);` is `fgets(stre, 999999, NULL);` as already pointed out by Fiddling Bits - your code isn't opening any file and invoking *undefined behavior*  in the `fgets` call

Comment: @UnholySheep i rectified that but still doesnt work

Comment: Suggest you run your program in a debugger to find out what it is doing exactly.

Comment: Try calling `fclose` in `genererN`. Also, check the contents of the file to see if it has been written out as expected. That is, do some basic debugging.

Comment: tryed fclose , doesnt change anything ,and i dont know how  to use the debugger

Comment: `replirtab()` expects an array of pointers. You're giving it an array of ints. You should be getting a warning when compiling it.

Comment: Your file has a blank line before each number because you're writing `\n` before and after each number. `replirtab()` doesn't skip the blank lines.

Comment: i want to have the change on the array saved and was told that was the method to do so

Comment: You were told wrong or misunderstood. Arrays are passed by reference, you don't need the extra indirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the following problems:

1. You're not closing the file after you write it, so the buffer isn't being flushed.
2. You're writing an extra newline before each number, but you don't skip it when reading.
3. `replirtab()` expects an array of pointers, but the array contains integers, not pointers. There's no need to indirect through the references. When you pass an array to a function, a pointer to the first element is passed.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void genererN ( int n){
    int i=0;
    FILE* fichier = NULL;
    fichier=fopen("valeurs.txt","w");
    if (!fichier) {
        printf("Unable to write file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (i<n){
        fprintf(fichier,"%d\n",rand());
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fichier);
}

void replirtab (int *t,int n){
    int i=0;int m;
    FILE* fichier = NULL;
    fichier=fopen("valeurs.txt","r");
    if (!fichier) {
        printf("Unable to read file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char stre[999999] = "";
    while(i<n){
        fgets(stre, 999999, fichier);
        m = atoi(stre);
        t[i]=m;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fichier);
}

void affichertab (int *t,int n){
    int i=0;
    while(i<n){
        printf("%d\n",t[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works , it would be great f you could explain to me what you did